# Get notification from nested async call with dispatch_group_async

Tags: ios, facebook, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

So I have situation when I've want do some async stuff, post status on Facebook and get notified when it's done posting. I was hoping that dispatch_group_async will do the job but now I hit the wall.

Here is how at this moment logic look like.

**Func**

```
func saveAndPost() {
    //1. save
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue) { () -> Void in
        print("saving to DB")
        //some func
        print("saved to DB")
    }
    //2. post
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, { () -> Void in
        print("publishing on FB")
        //some func
        //async request to ACAccount {
            print("access")
            //async performRequestWithHandler{
                print("posted")
                //anwser from request
                }
            }
        }
        print("published on FB")
    })

    dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, { () -> Void in
        print("done")
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            //go to next view
        })
    })
}
```

**Output**

```
saving to DB
saved to DB
publishing on FB
published on FB
done
post
posted
```

My goal is to get notified when whole posting process is done. Maybe this is not possible with dispatch_group_async and I have to use KVO or even PromiseKit?

**SOLUTION**

David got me thinking and `dispatch_group_enter` & 'dispatch_group_leave' right what I needed. So at this moment my logic look like this.

```
func saveAndPost() {
    //1. save
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue) { () -> Void in
        print("saving to DB")
        //some func
        print("saved to DB")
    }
    //2. post
    dispatch_group_enter(group)
        print("publishing on FB")
        //some func
        //async request to ACAccount {
            print("access")
            //async performRequestWithHandler{
                print("posted")
                //anwser from request
                dispatch_group_leave(group)
                }
            }
        }
        print("published on FB")

    dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, { () -> Void in
        print("done")
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            //go to next view
        })
    })
}
```

As you can see part **2.** is now modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred method to tackle this when dealing with async calls:

```
var asyncGroup = dispatch_group_create()

dispatch_group_enter(asyncGroup)
asyncCall1.start() {


  //end of callback
  dispatch_group_leave(asyncGroup)
}

dispatch_group_enter(asyncGroup)
asyncCall2.start() {

    asyncCall3.start() {

        asyncCall4.start() {

            dispatch_group_leave(asyncGroup)
        }

    }
}

dispatch_group_notify(asyncGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    println("done")
})
```

`asyncCall1.start() { ... }` and `asyncCall2.start() { ... }` are just sorta psuedocode to show you how it works.

Every `dispatch_group_enter` call needs to be balanced by a `dispatch_group_leave` call or you'll never get into the `dispatch_group_notify` block.